# EM Find behaves differently if Entity removed within same transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, entitymanager

It seems that the Hibernate EntityManager `find` method behaves differently in the following two cases:

Case 1 - Entity does not exist in the database before transaction starts. Within transaction, `find` of the entity returns `null`.

Case 2 - Entity exists in DB before transaction. Within transaction, entity is `remove`'d, then a `find` of the same key throws `EntityNotFoundException`.

Is this expected behaviour? Do I need to do a `flush` before the `find` for it to behave the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unexpected that `find` method in `EntityManager` throws `EntityNotFoundException` when entity is not found. [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#find%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object%29) is quite clear:

> **Returns:**
>   the found entity instance or null if the entity does not exist

This bug was reported in [HHH-7861](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-7861). It is fixed in 4.1.10, which is not yet released.

Comment: Thanks for that. At some point we will upgrade and this will no longer be an issue for us.

Answer (score 0):

OK, answering the second part of my question, it seems that a `flush` between the `remove` and the `find` in case 2 makes it behave the same as case 1. That is, the `find` just returns `null` without throwing an exception (which is what we want, as the exception triggers a rollback).

Answer points will go to anyone who can tell me **why** the `find` should behave differently.